# Outlook VBA - Is there an event triggered when a link is opened in an email?

Tags: vba, outlook

Occasionally my office's security group sends out fake phishing emails to make sure that everyone is able to avoid simple scams. Some are better than others and recently they've turned to more targeted spear-phishing and caught a lot of employees with their last email.

I've done well to avoid them so far but I wanted to add an extra layer of protection for myself in case I nearly fall for one in the future. So far, they've always been kind enough to send their phishing emails from an external address to mimic real attempts. These emails have a subject line like `[EXTERNAL] ..."` and direct you to click a link and prompt you to sign into an external portal.

My intent was to implement some vba that would **trigger when a link is clicked/followed in an email** which has `EXTERNAL` in the subject line, but I've had no luck finding any resources that follow a similar idea. I'm not even sure if it's possible, really. I've checked the [events for `MailItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem#events) but nothing really stands out as applicable to my needs.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such event, neither in the Outlook Object Model, not in the Word Object Model (you can get the Word editor and the `Document` object where the message is displayed from `Inspector.WordEditor`).

Comment: I guess I could instead have a macro that checks upon opening unread mail whether the subject contains `EXTERNAL`, and if so pop up a little msgbox to be careful when the hyperlink count > 0. Thank you!

Comment: You could, butt rather than looking for "EXTERNAL", check the sender address type - if it is "SMTP", you have an external sender.